# How can I exclude a measure range in my bank statement?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm modeling some of my yearly statement data from my checking account and I'd like to view my debits per month, but without my rent/utilities included. Now they fluctuate in price, so the numbers are anywhere between $775 and $1000. I'm trying to create a calc field that'll omit numbers in this range. Tableau says this calc is valid, and the logic seems there? It doesn't seem to be excluding those numbers..

```
if sum([Debits]) >=775 and sum([Debits]) <=1000
then sum([Debits])-1 'this is where I want those debits to be excluded
ELSE sum([Debits])
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try making it 0 instead:

```
if [Debits] >=775 and [Debits] <=1000
then 0
ELSE [Debits]
END
```

This would exclude these debits in the overall sum calculation.

Comment: I tried that beforehand, sorry, I should've specified. It's still not bringing down the total amount of debits for that month. For example, pre and post calc field for the month of May is $4400, regardless of that calc

Comment: I think you should be checking the condition without the sum in there, I have edited the solution. Check it out